# storing values from html to mysql via django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i want to send data to my mysql db via django. When i run server i dont get any error. When i submit form from hello.html, the values arent stored in my db. in DB i got table hello_cont

hello.html

```
   {% block content %}
    <form action="/polls/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

{% endblock %}

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class cont(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    comments= models.CharField(max_length=250)


def __str__(self):       


        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import cont

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = cont
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'comments')
```

view.py

```
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from .models import cont
    from .forms import PostForm


    def hello(request):
            return render(request, 'polls/hello.html')
    def post_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.name = request.user
                post.email = request.email
                post.comments = request.comments
                post.save()
    else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form

})
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.views import hello
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'', include('polls.urls')),
```

]

Comment: form is send to `/polls` (`action="/polls"`). What you have in `urls.py' ? Is `/polls` assigned to `post_new` ?

Comment: Your form is presumably not passing validation, but you don't show any of the errors in the template.

Comment: btw: you can always use `print()` in code and run Django server in terminal to see printed text - ie values in variables, `if form.is_valid()`, etc.

Comment: I added my main urls.py
I get 200 http response